# Fourier Transform excruciatingly slow

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, dft

Before I get judged, I am no expert with this and simply for the sake of curiosity I tried to write some code that performs a Fourier transform. After watching [3Blue1Brown's video on fourier transform](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spUNpyF58BY) I wanted to write the algorithm myself and plot it, simply because... well it looks cool. I tried to do everything in pure python only using numpy and matplotlib, and it sort of works.

Notice: I am plotting everything iteratively, and re-plotting at each increment

But, plotting the wound up wave and the transform is very very slow. I think I am doing some things inefficiently, maybe even wrong.

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

u = np.linspace(-8*np.pi, 8*np.pi, 1000)
sin1 = np.sin(u) + 2

u2 = np.linspace(-3*np.pi, 3*np.pi, 1000)
sin2 = np.sin(u2) + 2
plt.plot(u + u2, sin1 + sin2)
fig, (winder, integax) = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, ncols = 1)

L = len(sin1)
real = []
imag = []
integral = []

for val in np.arange(0.00001,360,0.00001):
    real = []
    imag = []
    for t,si in zip(np.arange(0,L,val),sin1 + sin2):
        complex = si * np.e ** (2 * np.pi * 1j * t)
        real.append(complex.real)
        imag.append(complex.imag)

    fig.set_size_inches(10,10)
    point = np.trapz(real)
    integral.append(point)
    #print(integral[-1], time[-1])
    integax.plot(integral)
    winder.plot(real, imag, 'b-')
    plt.pause(0.00001)
    winder.cla()

ax = plt.plot(real, imag, 'b-')
plt.show()
```

Now I would like to plot it faster, and I think that the integration part is not correct. Since no spikes occur in the resulting plot even after waiting for a long time.

I also don't think that I am using linspace correctly to plot sine waves nor am I doing the frequency part right in the fourier formula.

Comment: If I understood your code, you are using numerical integration with the trapezoidal rule. If you want to compute a Fourier Transform and do it fast, then you should probably implement a [Fast Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform). Note that the FFT is considered (along the Kalman Filter) to be one of the most important algorithms in engineering.

Comment: I have heard of the fast fourier transform and wanted to tackle it after I mastered the discrete, as I'm afraid that it might be a little be too advanced for me. In any case, I can live with the speed constraints right now, as this is just a little  demonstration I wanted to present for my lab. I just that maybe the slowness could be due to how I plot the wave and the integral of it, and not the integration itself.

Comment: You're approximating a continuous Fourier transform - the discrete Fourier transform(DFT) would use a sum rather than integration.

Comment: @AhmadMoussa : If you are not sure about which step is taking longer in your code, then you need to perform a profiling operation on it, see for instance [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script)

Comment: `matplotlib` can introduce quite a bit of overhead when you repeatedly plot (although @Metifico is right about profiling to be sure).  Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48697184/faster-plotting-of-real-time-audio-signal/48698434#48698434 for some hints on how to speed up matplotlib (although it's about `imshow`, `plot` can be treated similarly).

Comment: Thank you both for the suggestions, I will make sure to have a look at the link.

Answer (score 0):

Compiling comments into an answer:

If I understood your code, you are using numerical integration with the trapezoidal rule. If you want to compute a Fourier Transform and do it fast, then you should probably implement a [Fast Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) algorithm. Note that the FFT is considered (along with the Kalman Filter) to be one of the most important algorithms in engineering, and for a good reason: It is so much faster than naive implementations of the Fourier transform that it turns intractable problems into computing demanding but feasible products.

As mentioned be @user2699, there are methods to speed up plotting, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48697184/faster-plotting-of-real-time-audio-signal/48698434#48698434).

This addresses some algorithmic and Python related bottlenecks of your code, but if you are dissatisfied with the speed it takes to run, the go-to starting point should be [profiling your code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)), and some hints on how to do this with Python have been discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script).